# Getting the value of a cell, instead of the its address, to be the parameter for an Excel formula

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

There is a column with values, and a new one is added everyday( with the date in the adjacent column). I would need to get the average of every three months automatically. While it is pretty easy to do so for the past data, I was wondering if it is possible to have a formula where the date can be selected, and the average of the data till the last cell is taken in until the specified date is reached. For example:

Column A has dates say from 7/1/2012 to 7/23/2012.
Column B has certain values.

Both have a new entry every day (barring weekends). Is it possible for me to get the average till the last entered date (7/23/2012 in this case), but only valid till the date reaches say 9/30/2012 ?

Comment: What version of Excel?  If 2007+, you could maybe try using the AVERAGEIFS() worksheet function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel, dates can be represented as numbers, more specifically the number of days since January 1st, 1900.  In this case, you want to cap the days at September 30th, 2012, which is represented as 41182.  And so you can compute the average of the values in column B such that the associated dates in column A are earlier than October 2012 with this formula:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B:B, A:A, "<41183")
```

If you wanted to set a range of dates, say from between July 1st, 2012 to September 30th, 2012, you'd do it like this:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B:B, A:A, "<41183", A:A, ">41090")
```

Just play around with dates and their number representation to get the proper bounds.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect! That will make my job much easier with this spread, and going forward as well! Thanks a ton, much appreciated.